# SessionNotCreatedException in Selenium: Chrome Failed to Start, DevToolsActivePort File Missing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

this is my chrome and chrome driver version
ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-120:~$ chrome --version
Google Chrome for Testing 120.0.6099.109
ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-120:~$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.109 (3419140ab665596f21b385ce136419fde0924272-refs/branch-heads/6099@{#1483})
ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-120:~$ cat scrape

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set up Chrome options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Bypass OS security model
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU hardware acceleration
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") # Overcome limited resource problems

chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chrome"

# Specify the path to ChromeDriver using Service

chromedriver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

# Initialize the Chrome driver with specified options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Now you can use `driver` to interact with Chrome in headless mode

# For example, opening a webpage:

driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Do your scraping tasks or automated testing here...

# Close the browser when done

driver.quit()```

ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-120:\~$ python3 scrape
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/scrape", line 19, in \<module\>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)\["value"\]
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
\#0 0x55922a5cdf83 \<unknown\>
\#1 0x55922a286cf7 \<unknown\>
\#2 0x55922a2be60e \<unknown\>
\#3 0x55922a2bb26e \<unknown\>
\#4 0x55922a30b80c \<unknown\>
\#5 0x55922a2ffe53 \<unknown\>
\#6 0x55922a2c7dd4 \<unknown\>
\#7 0x55922a2c91de \<unknown\>
\#8 0x55922a592531 \<unknown\>
\#9 0x55922a596455 \<unknown\>
\#10 0x55922a57ef55 \<unknown\>
\#11 0x55922a5970ef \<unknown\>
\#12 0x55922a56299f \<unknown\>
\#13 0x55922a5bb008 \<unknown\>
\#14 0x55922a5bb1d7 \<unknown\>
\#15 0x55922a5cd124 \<unknown\>
\#16 0x7f67bb294ac3 \<unknown\>
````